# PySpark - Convert String to Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column in my dataframe that is a string with the value like `["value_a", "value_b"]`.

What is the best way to convert this column to Array and explode it? For now, I'm doing something like:

```
explode(split(col("value"), ",")).alias("value")
```

But I'm getting strings like `["awesome"` or `"John"` or `"Maria]"` and the expected output should be `awesome`, `John`, `Maria` (one item per line, that why i'm using explode).

Sample code to reproduce:

```
sample_input = [
  {"id":1,"value":"[\"johnny\", \"maria\"]"},
  {"id":2,"value":"[\"awesome\", \"George\"]"}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_input)

df.select(col("id"), explode(split(col("value"), ",")).alias("value")).show(n=10)
```

Output generated by code above:

```
+---+----------+
| id|     value|
+---+----------+
|  1| ["johnny"|
|  1|  "maria"]|
|  2|["awesome"|
|  2| "George"]|
+---+----------+
```

Expected should be:

```
+---+----------+
| id|    value|
+---+----------+
|  1| johnny |
|  1| maria  |
|  2| awesome|
|  2| George|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Why are you taking array as string first, It should taken as array. You can apply explode on array, no need to split it.

Comment: try use from_json and then explode: `df.withColumn('value', explode(from_json('value','array<string>'))).show()`

Answer (score -2):

Worked for me.

```
sample_input = [
  {"id":1,"value":["johnny", "maria"]},
  {"id":2,"value":["awesome", "George"]}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_input)

df.select(col("id"), explode(col("value")).alias("value")).show(n=10)
+---+-------+
| id|  value|
+---+-------+
|  1| johnny|
|  1|  maria|
|  2|awesome|
|  2| George|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: You changed the question- the escaped double quotes are the problem, and you removed them from the example you posted. Also: [Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable).

Comment: @pault I don't see any issue in suggesting use array as array not as string. Data was hard-coded. If it is not expected answer people can inform in comments and accordingly answer can be edited. That is why we have that feature. Anyways, thanks for the update.